# how to prove $\displaystyle f(x,y) = e^{-1/(x^2+y^2)}\frac{2x}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ is bounded?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions

$$f(x,y) = e^{-1/(x^2+y^2)}\frac{2x}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$ for $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$  and $f(x,y) = 0$ for $x = y = 0$.

Comment: Put for $x^2+y^2\not =0$  $u=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}$. We have $|x|\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}$. Then $|f(x,y)|\leq 2u\sqrt{u}\exp(-u)=g(u)$. Hence you have only to show that $g(u)$ is bounded on $[0,+\infty[$, that is easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is continuous everywhere. To see that the limit at the origin is $0,$ note that although the rational function sometimes becomes unbounded at the origin as the variables become arbitrarily small, depending on the manner of approach (go along $x=y,$ for example), the function $f(x,y)$ yet goes to $0$ at the origin since the exponential function tends to $0.$

Thus, it suffices to check the boundaries of the domain since the function, being continuous, will automatically be bounded in any compact subdomain. Thus, as the variables become arbitrarily large, again the rational function tends to $0,$ and the exponential function goes to $1.$ Thus the function is everywhere finite, and therefore must be bounded.

Comment: The rational function $2x/(x^2+y^2)^2$ does not tend to zero as $(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)$. For instance along the line where $y=0$, we have $2x/(x^2+y^2)^2=2x/(x^2)^2=1/x^3\rightarrow\infty$ as $x\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @M1183 That's true. However, $f(x,y)$ still vanishes at the origin since the exponential function goes to $0.$